# Keeping check boxes selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a html page that can be used to keep track on what you have watched by manual clicking check boxes so you know what episode you are on. My problem is keeping the box checked after leaving the page and returning to it, I have been trying to use cookies but none have worked so far. I am using this on Google Chrome and not sure if this makes a difference.

```
    <h2>Season 1</h2>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option1"/>Episode 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option2"/>Episode 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option3"/>Episode 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option4"/>Episode 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option5"/>Episode 5</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="option6"/>Episode 6</li>
</ul>
```

This is the Javascript code I used:

```
        <script>
  function handleButtonClick(button){
    if ($(button).text().match("Check all")){
      $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
    } else {
      $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
    };
    updateButtonStatus();
  }
  function updateButtonStatus(){
    var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
    $("button").text(allChecked? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
  }
  function updateCookie(){
    var elementValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
    $.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  }
  function repopulateFormELements(){
    var elementValues = $.cookie('elementValues');
    if(elementValues){
      Object.keys(elementValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = elementValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });
      $("button").text(elementValues["buttonText"])
    }
  }
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateCookie();
  });
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    handleButtonClick(this);
    updateCookie();
  });
  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateFormELements();
</script>
```

Here is a link to the full document: http://jsfiddle.net/r4gqqd0c/
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you should use server side code for the functionality you want.

Comment: Bear in mind that the use of cookies, or localStorage, restricts the user to one machine (unless they're willing to re-enter the same data multiple times across multiple devices). Whereas a server-side solution – with a membership system to correlate users with their data – would allow the use of multiple devices with no repetition.

Comment: Yeah I realized about the data staying to one person but I have about no knowledge with server side code like PHP and mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a database to store checkbox status you can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). An example will be like:

```js
//add this when a checkbox is clicked
$(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).prop("checked"));
});
//when page loads
$(":checkbox").each(function() {
  var status = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id"));
  $(this).prop("checked", status === "true" ? true : false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Season 1</h2>

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1" />Episode 1</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2" />Episode 2</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3" />Episode 3</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option4" />Episode 4</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option5" />Episode 5</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option6" />Episode 6</li>
</ul>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnr9hmo2/)

**References:**

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment how would I add the top code so when the checkbox is clicked it activates it?

Comment: @Ben check update code and fiddle. The working example is in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks the code you made works in the jsfiddle but when I use the code it doesn't heres my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjpojeeo/

Comment: You need to provide an id for each checkbox. Also you need to use `each` when document is ready in jquery. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjpojeeo/1/)

Comment: Glad that I helped you.